# How to read file paths with escape characters in pandas read_csv while accepting user input?

Tags: python, string, pandas, string-literals

**I am trying to accept a path from a user, and then load the spreadsheet at that path:**

```
df_path = input('What is the file path?')
df = pd.read_csv(df_path, index_col=2)
```

Some users, when pasting their paths in, are told it is invalid, because of escape sequences. Here, `\166` is being converted to `v`:

```
df_path = input('What is the file path?')
```

C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv `#entered by user`

```
df = pd.read_csv(df_path, index_col=2)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Datav - data\\data.csv"
```

I'm aware that manually loading the path within the code, this can be accounted for:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv", index_col=2)
```

However, I can't find a way to make this work while **accepting user input** and **storing it as a variable** (tried many ways of attempting to do so, one example here):

```
df_path = input('What is the file path?')
```

"C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv" `#entered by user`

```
df = pd.read_csv("r'" + df_path, index_col=2)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "r'C:\\Datav - data\\data.csv"
```

It also doesn't work to try to rewrite the path, replacing `\` with `\\`:

```
df_path = df_path.replace("\", "\\")

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

-

```
df_path = df_path.replace(r"\", r"\\")

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What happens if you replace the '\' with '\\'?

Answer (score 1):

You're turning `\166` into v, you'll need to replace with `\\166`

The reason it works with `r'\166'` is because you are telling the interpreter to take the string literally. Where the backslash is *literally* a backslash.

In your work around you've appended a string `"r'"` to the front of another string, which is why it doesn't find the directory `"r'C:/"`.

In short, `"r'string'"` is not the same as `r'string'` where the r is outside the string quotations.

Here is a [break down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/3407256) on raw strings.

If you add the r to the front of the string in your 2nd code block you should get a working solution, like so:

```
df_path = r"C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv"
```

Or writing the string with two backslashes will do the same:

```
df_path = "C:\\Data\\166 - data\\data.csv"
```

Comment: No, because once it's read by the interpreter it becomes `v` so you can't reverse this process.

Comment: Attempting to do as in line 1 also does not work. I still do not see a solution. I've tried to clarify the problem, as the second half of your response didn't quite address the question.

Comment: If they are pasting their paths into the actual .py file then they need to be r"C:/directory" strings

Comment: They are not doing so. It prompts them for the paths, using `input`, and they respond.

Comment: You need to make this clear in your question what the users are doing, not displaying their input as part of the .py

Comment: I've now made adjustments to clarify the issue.

Comment: The normal behaviour of python 'input' is not to convert strings as described.  Please test this yourself.  Do not simple try input in idle, which may appear to map as your first statement, but any expression with a '\' will display as a double '\\' when output in idle.  The data from the input itself is not mapped, only the displayed value.  To test in idle, input to a variable, then print the variable

Answer (score 0):

This is now clearer. Python 3.5 is the version, and the code:

```
df_path = input('What is the file path?')
```

It is clear why testing with a string when wrong.  Setting df_path from a literal will give an error, and you need a raw_string to avoid that error.

However data from input should be the same as a raw_string already.  No conversion is needed. 
Testing this with a simple program:

```
a= "C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv"  # the \ characters here will be mapped
b= r"C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv"  # the r means \ will not be special
c= input("? ")  # data from input is already treated like the r"\" above
print(a==c,b==c)
print(c)
```

With python 3.5 Produces:

```
? C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv
False True
C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv
>>>
```

In idle, or in windows 'cmd', in powershell or in bash shell(although the example is clearly for windows) the result is as above with the input being equal to the r"" string.  This indicates the normal behaviour of python is to treat input exactly as a raw string, equivalent to using r'' in code.

So it could be that from your test you though you needed to emulate the raw_string with the r"",  and this is the only error.

If you are saying the people get the 'v' when typing the string, this would be something different.

Are you saying that users are  entering `C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv` as resulting in a df_path which prints as `'C:\\Datav - data\\data.csv'` instead of the correct data which would print as `'C:\\Data\\166 - data\\data.csv'`

Or only that you were trying to prevent this from happening, because you assumed this would happen?

If it is actually happening, the problem is not python itself.  Either the actual console environment or terminal the program is being run from is doing its own translation of \166 into the escape character, or some other processing in the application is modifying the string.  If the program works with the `df_path = r'C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv'` in place of input, then it can only be the environment where the string is being entered, or the input itself has been changed from the standard python input.

But I suspect you found an error when trying to replace the `input` with setting from a string, and tried to code around a problem that would never actually exist with the `input`, just with your test data.

Note:  As explained by @GiantsLoveDeathMetal, A python 'rawstring' with an r'' before the quotes, changes the reading of the program file itself by python.  You cannot make a string with an 'r' within the string to reproduce how this works. The r is outside the quotes and is telling python how to read the original string, and this is all done before the program executes.  The same rule also applies to f'' strings in python 3.6.

Comment: It is Python 3.5, why does this appear to be Python 2.x to you? Also, I do not assume the user enters their path in quotes... that's just the string representation. I've tried to clarify the question, because there seems to be some miscommunication here.

Comment: I updated the reply given the extra information.  You can try this test program in your environment to verify

Answer (score 0):

I am having a little difficulty replicating the issue.  Perhaps add in an extra line to see if it helps?

```
df_path = "C:\Data\166 - data\data.csv"
file_path = str(df_path)
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=2)
```